# Best practice for editing multiple images in the same way

Tags: images, image-processing

I have a project that I'm working on that requires me to edit 8 similar images in the exact same way.

In other words, I need some way that whatever I change on the first image, I need to be able to do to all the other images in the exact same way.

At first I tried to simply hack at it and hope they turned out okay, but that failed. Next I tried to record a desktop macro, but I couldn't seem to find any appropriate free software solutions that would work on Windows 7.

Is there an easy way about this? My last idea is to just go ahead and edit the images in GIMP and precisely record each of the coordinates and repeat the same way. Is there a simple program I can run?

Comment: You'll have to specify more details about what you mean with editing "in the exact same way".

Comment: GIMP has scripting capabilities, although I've never used them.  See: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-scripting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gimp does in fact have a [batch mode](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/):

> GIMP comes with a so-called batch mode that allows you to do image
>   processing from the command line. It also makes it easy to apply the
>   same set of operations to a number of images. We have got a lot of
>   questions on the mailing-lists on how to use the batch mode and this
>   small page tries to explain the basics to you.

(Scripting is done in the extremely creepy Lisp language if that's a turn-off, though.)

So does [Photoshop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7425a.html):

> The Batch command runs an action on a folder of files. If you have a
>   digital camera or a scanner with a document feeder, you can also
>   import and process multiple images with a single action. Your scanner
>   or digital camera may need an acquire plug-in module that supports
>   actions.